# Can Yii1 legacy app be connected to Yii2, such that Yii2 takes care of unit/functional testing

Tags: unit-testing, yii, yii2, phpunit

Guys we built our product on Yii1 framework, and there is a lot of code, and lets just assume that currently for us to migrate to Yii2 is not an option.

Now Yii1 unit / functional / acceptance testing and PHPunit is broken, we are having a difficult time getting a solution. We are kind of trapped in Yii1.

One ray of hope comes from the fact that there are ways available through which Yii2 can be connected to Yii1 (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-both-yii2-yii1)

Is it possible / feasible to connect my current app to Yii2 and then manage all the unit / functional testing through Yii2. So that my app remains happy in Yii1 and Yii2 takes care of the testing part.

[Here is a Visualization of what I am asking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Cu0.png)

Experts suggest please

Answer (score 0):

Tbh I cannot see any point in moving the testing part to Yii2. When it comes to unit testing it is not possible because the code that you are testing is already written in Yii the only thing you can choose from is testing framework (PHPunit, Codeception).

I realise that certain frameworks make it easier to test your code but in each of them you can write testable and untestable code. My personal experience is that Yii2 does not make it easier to write testable code, especially with static `find()`.

You can look into behavior testing. It makes you focus on features/behavior instead of code specs and makes tests easier to read.

In the end adding Yii2 to your stack would not make testing easier. The best option is to hire contractor that would take look at your codebase and give you proper training and clean the mess up.